# Make your computer discoverable

Tags: bluetooth

my .net app on the computer needs to make the computer discoverable, start a service and then wait to accept incoming connections. my app/computer is the slave and connecting device is the master. So I change my local radio mode to discoverable programmatically,start my service and wait... But when the device is supposed to connect to my app/computer, nothing happens.

Windows help and support has this :

```
Control Panel ->search for bluetooth -> click on change bluetooth settings ->
To make your computer discoverable to Bluetooth enabled devices, 
select the check box for Allow Bluetooth devices to find this computer. 

When a Bluetooth enabled computer is in discovery mode, it broadcasts a 
wireless signal that allows it to be detected by other computers or devices. 
This is sometimes called pairing mode. If you check this box, your computer 
will still be able to detect Bluetooth enabled devices that are in discovery mode,
but they will not be able to detect your computer.
```

I am not quite sure what's the context. If I leave that box checked, then other devices will be able to detect me (because I am set to discoverable), but won't be able to connect????? So my service just keeps listening, won't be able to detect any incoming requests? Am I right?

Comment: You can enable device discovery - it means that other devices will be able to see it. You can enable device incoming connections - it means that other devices can connect to it. More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362776(v=vs.85).aspx